# Separate menu's with php

Tags: php, session

```
<?php
$nav ="";
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $navigatie = [
        'index.php' => 'Home',
        'addbar.php' => "Add Bar",
        'addbooze.php' => "Add Booze",
        'addresto.php' => "Add Resto",
        'addfood.php' => "Add Food",
        'bars.php' => "Check bars",
        'users.php' => "gebruikers",

    ];}
else{
    $navigatie = [
        'index.php' => 'Home',
        'login.php' => 'Login',
        'registreer.php' => 'Registreer',
    ];
}

foreach ($navigatie as $key => $value){
    $attr = '';
    if( $key == $current )
    {
        $attr = ' class="active"';
    }
    $nav .= '<li' . $attr . '><a href=" '. $key . '">' . $value . '</a></li>';
}

?>


<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper light-blue darken-1">

        <ul >
            <?php echo $nav ?>
        </ul>
        <ul class="right-align">
            <li><a class="right-align red darken-4" href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

My question is, how can I add my addbar.php & addbooze.php and addresto.php & addfood.php in a dropdown menu? I'm using materialize as library. My menu is now a long menu bar and very ugly. It is controlled with a session and the dropdown has to disappear when the session isn't started.

Comment: Please be more specific as to what the problem is. Also it'd be helpful if you can share a screenshot.

Comment: so, did you start the session? and in all files using them?

Comment: @Fred-ii- At the moment the session is started then you have to see te if otherwise you only can see the else.

Comment: @Rahul http://imgur.com/cIgTiFh

Comment: @Rahul http://imgur.com/cIgTiFh So add Bar & Add Booze has to go in to 1 dropdown and Add Resto & Add food has to go in 1 dropdown.

Comment: You could use a ternary operator. It's more effective.

Comment: Have you checked this out?- http://materializecss.com/dropdown.html

Comment: @Rahul I did this yes. But how do you do it with php in a simple way. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this CSS initially,

```
<style>
/* Style The Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
</style>
```

then use this HTML Code for your Drop down Menu,

```
<?php
$nav ="";
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $navigatie = [
        'index.php' => 'Home',
        'addbar.php' => "Add Bar",
        'addbooze.php' => "Add Booze",
        'addresto.php' => "Add Resto",
        'addfood.php' => "Add Food",
        'bars.php' => "Check bars",
        'users.php' => "gebruikers",

    ];}
else{
    $navigatie = [
        'index.php' => 'Home',
        'login.php' => 'Login',
        'registreer.php' => 'Registreer',
    ];
}
?>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <?php
    foreach ($navigatie as $key => $value){
       $attr = '';
       if( $key == $current )
       {
          $attr = ' class="active"';
       }
     ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></a>
    <?php 
     } 
     ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the answer in my pen-
http://codepen.io/xRahul/pen/KNjOWy

Include these Libraries at the top

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Then use this HTML

```
      <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
      <a class='dropdown-button btn' href='#' data-activates='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a>

      <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
      <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
        <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
      </ul>
```

So just add your php in the html above and you're good to go!